# Adding values to mongodb by using Linux shell script

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, mongodb, loops

Here im trying to push some values to mongodb this is my pseudo code

```
 while read LINE
    do          
     addRow $para1 $param1 #pass value to the mongo
    done < ${FILE}

    function addRow() {
    para1="$1";
    para2="$2";
        if [ ! -z "$para1" ]
        then
             echo $1 $2;
             mongo dbname <<EOF
                newstuff = [{ "name" : "${1}", "age" : "${2}" }]
                db.collectionname.insert(newstuff);
             EOF
        else
           echo “Failed”;
        fi

    }
```

Its working fine, but i think that's not a proper way to do that job, i can see connect was re establish every time, any expertise suggestions may helpful

```
#### Process

bye
#file1

connecting to: dbname
[
     ##proc 1
]
bye
#file 2

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: dbname
[
        ##proc 2
]
bye

#file3
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: dbname
[
        ##proc 3
]
bye
```

Comment: Why not script it using a language like Perl, Ruby, NodeJS and call that from your script? As is, you're starting/stopping the console each time. You'd need to batch up all of the instructions and call into the console once if you want to use the same connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each LINE in the FILE contains two parameters, I would first build the JS object for all the contents, then add it to mongo with one call:

```
items=()
while read para1 para2; do
    items+=( "$(printf '{"name":"%s","age":"%s"}' "$para1" "$para2")" )
done < "$FILE"
js_list=$(IFS=,; echo "[${items[*]}]")

mongo dbname <<EOF
newstuff = $js_list
db.collectionname.insert(newstuff);
EOF
```

Comment: @glenn-jackson Thank you very much mate !!, this is what im waiting for. can you explain the $(IFS=,; echo "[${items[*]}]") part for further modifications.

Comment: That joins the array elements with commas. The form `"${array[*]}"` (quotes mandatory) joins the array elements using the first characters of $IFS.